# Github gist with three files

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Github gist.

The primary file is 'script.py'

I want to include two additional files, both are .txt files

Regardless of the order I attempt to add the three files to my gist
one of the two .txt files assumes precedence over the script.py file.

The script.py file program includes two python context managers:
1). a decorator (containing a generator function) based context manager
script.py imports context manager from contextlib

2). a class based context manager
The purpose of both context managers is to generate either a 'generic' or 'personalized'
birthday card, thank you card, or a general 'greeting' card that is neither thank you nor birthday.

I would like to better understand the difference between a .py and .txt file as far as GitHub is concerned.  (I have looked at some documentation but it does not expand enough)

If the code block(s) is/are expecting a .txt file to be passed when called, then don't I
have to add/save these files as .txt files in my GitHub gist?
Or can the .txt files be saved as .py files and still be interpreted without errors?

And if GitHub is saving the gist with a .txt extension won't that create an error when I call it?